# When do you stop Minocycline/Spirnolactone prior to start of Accutane?

Tags: medications, dermatology, acne, drug-tapering-weaning, accutane

I will be meeting with my Dermatologist to start on Accutane Sept. 16. She is on vacation now so I cannot contact her, but she mentioned that before I start Acutane that I need to stop taking my Minocycline and Spirnolactone, but I can't recall how far in advance that is. Is it a month or two weeks? (Also, yes, I know that I need to take a blood test at the start of the month and be on birth control and sign the "I pledge" and all that jazz). Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is a very interesting, yet tricky, question. The reason you must stop taking the minocycline is because of the interaction between tetracyclines (minocycline) and vitamin A (Retinoic acid) derivatives (isotretinoin/Accutane) causes a pseudotumor cerebri also known as increased intracranial pressure, which can be deadly.

Now when taking spironolactone and isotretinoin, I don't see a problem per se, as far as interactions go. However, maybe your doctor doesn't want you to endure any of spironolactone's side effects as it will be minimally effective in treating the acne **by comparison** to the isotretinoin.

Comment: Do you know how much prior to start date of Acutane though?